# Relation between KL and marginal-KL divergences between distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be a random variable distributed according to a (absolutely continuous) probability distribution $P$. Let $N$ be the Gaussian distribution with zero mean and identity covariance. One way to measure the difference/discrepency between $P$ and $N$ is via KL divergence $$KL(P||N) = \int \log{\left(\frac{dP}{dN}\right)}dP.$$
One can also measure the difference between $P$ and $N$ using marginal KL divergences. Let $P_u$ be the marginal distribution of $P$ along direction $u$; that is, $P_u$ is the distribution of random variable $u^TX$. Similarly, let $N_u$ be the marginal distribution of $N$ along direction $u$. Then I'm going to define $KL_M$ as follows $$KL_M(P||N) = \max_{u: \|u\|_2 = 1} KL(P_u||N_u).$$
I'm interested in the relationship between $KL_M(P||N)$ and $KL(P||N)$. Clearly, $KL_M(P||N)=0$ iff $KL(P||N)=0$. This suggests that these two quantities could be related to each other. But I'm unable to quantify this relationship.
Is $\frac{KL_M(P||N)}{KL(P||N)}$ upper and lower bounded by some constant? Or, are there distributions $P$ for which $\frac{KL_M(P||N)}{KL(P||N)}$ can be arbitrarily close to $0$ or arbitrarily large?

Comment: It is upper bounded by 1 by data processing of KL divergence; http://www.stat.yale.edu/~yw562/teaching/598/lec04.pdf, I don't know any lower bound per-se, you can easily get 1/d by picking d dimensional gaussians, so as d grows large, that can approach 0. I would also guess that that is a lower bound by invoking the chain rule of KL divergence, but I am not sure (thus not answering)

Comment: (Note that 1 is a tight upper bound, just pick a gaussian that is the same in $d-1$ dimensions)